# Getting Subset in a functional way

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to implement a function which gets an array A of n elements and a number k as input, and returns an array with all the subsets of size k of A (each subset will be an array itself).

Define the type of the function, and implement at least 3 tests for the function (using assert). It should be in Javascript/Typescript and functional

For example: FunSubsets ([1,2,3],2) => [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator function with one more parameter for the temporary result set.

```js
function* subsets(values, size, parts = []) {
    var i;

    size--;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (size) {
            yield* subsets(values.slice(i + 1), size, [...parts, values[i]]);
        } else {
            yield [...parts, values[i]];
        }
    }
}

console.log([...subsets([1, 2, 3], 2)]);
console.log([...subsets([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

loop through the array and for each element you loop again to create a slice with the length `k - 1` that you concatenate with the current element of the first loop and you push it to a temporary array that you return in the end.

```js
let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let k = 2;

function subSet(arr, k) {

  let tmpArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      let slice = arr.slice(j, j + k - 1);
      slice.push(arr[i]);
      tmpArr.push(slice.reverse());
    }
  }
  return tmpArr;
}

let mySubSets = subSet(myArr, k);

console.log(JSON.stringify(mySubSets));
```